# iOS with Parse. PFUser.currentuser() not getting cached. Returns nil after app restart

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, parse-platform, pfuser

I am building an app with Parse in swift. PFUser.currentuser() always returns nil after the app is stopped and run again. I am using the iOS simulator and the local datastore is enabled.
I am using something like this -

```
if PFUser.currentuser() == nil {
// Perform segue to login screen
}
```

And for login I am using

```
PFUser.loginWithUsernameInBackground(...)
```

The currentuser remains till the app is restarted, after which it is reset to nil. I have even tried to pin the currentuser but it doesn't work.
How can I check if the currentuser is being cached locally.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Got the same issue here.

Comment: Try making the call with a block return. Are you getting back the expected user and a nil error back? Also make sure this call is done after calling setApplicationId

Answer (score 2):

For me, the reason is simply the following part is not executed. Be careful of multi-thread. Usually that's the cause.

```
Parse.setApplicationId("xx","xx")
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not resetting the simulator and are running on the same one? It should not clear the currentUser.
Is it possible you are calling

```
PFUser.logout()
```

in 'applicationWillTerminate' in AppDelegate or anywhere else?

Comment: No not using PFUser.logout(). But I am using core data. So my 'appWillTerminate' does include a self.saveContext() call.