# PFUser.becomeInBackground never returns in watchOS2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, apple-watch, watchos-2

In watchOS2 I am getting the sessionToken from the iOS app with WCSession. That works great but when I try to call become in background it never returns. The console logs 1 and 2 but never makes it to print("3"). Any reason becomeInBackground wouldn't respond at all? Or is there a completely different way I should be going about this?

The sessionToken is coming from user.sessionToken in iOS.

```
print("1")
if let sessionToken = reply["sessionToken"] as? String {
    print("2")
    PFUser.becomeInBackground(sessionToken, block: { (user, error) in
        print("3")
        if let user = user as? User where error == nil {
           print("success")
        } else {
           print(error)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this @Jeremiah?

Comment: Nope. Any help would be appreciated! I'm stuck.

Comment: Did you make sure you authenticated your app with Parse at the launch of your app (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34151042/1148702)? That was the problem for us

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I had that line in there but must have deleted it at some point. More work to do but becomeInBackground is returning now.